# Algorithm ----Where I can get the algorithm resource-----Schedule algorithm and so on

Tags: algorithm, resources

I wonder If there is a place provided many algorithms.
I want to know the details of some process´s  schedule algorithms.

For example, If I want to get some informations about Network, I will check out the RFC documents. I want to know, in the field of os algorithms ,if there is something like RFC.

Further more, If there is a place I can read lots of algorithms in many fields. In my view, Reading the algorithms in many fields can help me a lot in algorithm ------Anyway, someday, maybe I can combine two algorithms to solve one particular problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to know about algorithms in general read a good book. "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen et. al. is a good place to start. For algorithms specific to some area (e.g. bioinformatics), find a book that covers that area in some depth, and you will probably find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

How about this: [List of Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms). Also you can study Donald Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming Vol 1 - 4.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has lots of them. I don't think that there is not any organization that provides algorithms for OS.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_algorithm) holds a lot of algorithms.

Use section "See Also" there.